# Trying to control my heating recirc pump Aplha1L Grundfos, with a signal from thermocouple. What connections are used on the pump to connect stat

Tags: pump, thermocouple

I can run the system on manually and it works fine but I don't know how to connect the thermocouple to the pump so it's turned on when water hits a certain temperature and gets off when the temperature drops below this set point. I purchased the pump an Alpha 1L and the thermocouple which has three connections and a slot next to the main power source to the pump which has three possible connections...is that the one ? What wires go where...? Any help very much appreciated. Thx in advance.enter thermocouple.
[image: pump][image: system set up]